# SQL Single quote and double quote inserting values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-constant

Im trying to create a table and insert this value here:

```
("Where I'm Calling From: Selected Stories", 'Raymond', 'Carver', 1989, 12, 526),
```

Im having an issue with using single and double quotes. How would I amend this ? and what should I keep in mind for future?

Using Microsoft SQL Server management 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use single quote, and double single quote when needed.

```
('Where I''m Calling From: Selected Stories', 'Raymond', 'Carver', 1989, 12, 526)
```

Answer (score 1):

double quotes cannot be used for insert. use single quotes.
you can use single quotes twice for escaping. `''`

```
insert into .... values 
 ('Where I''m Calling From: Selected Stories', 'Raymond', 'Carver', 1989, 12, 526)
```